# How to access form control from within ToString method of nested struct

Tags: c#, nested-class

I am building a small windows form application in C#.  Within the form code I define a public struct with a ToString method that must build part of its output from items in comboBoxes on the same form.  This doesn't sound like it should be difficult

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 public struct OrderLineItem
    {
     string someString;
     int index;
     string ToString()
        {return someString + ActiveForm.sizeComboBox.Items[index].ToString();}  
    }
}
```

It complains that it cannot find a definition for sizeComboBox.  If I explicitly use the name of the form, it says an object reference is required for the static field...
I'm not quite sure what it means by that.  Using this.sizeComboBox refers to the struct, not the form.  Using just sizeComboBox, again, an object reference is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The struct knows about its containing class *type*, but it doesn't know about any particular instance of that type, unless you tell it. For example, you can create a constructor that takes a Form1 object, and it can save a reference to that form in a member variable.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
 public struct OrderLineItem 
    { 
     string someString; 
     int index; 
     Form1 parentForm;

     internal OrderLineItem(Form1 parentForm)
     {
         this = new OrderLineItem();
         this.parentForm = parentForm;
     }

     string ToString() 
     {
         if (parentForm == null)
             return string.Empty;
         else
             return someString + parentForm.sizeComboBox.Items[index].ToString();
     }   
    } 
}
```

That said, this is a seriously questionable design.

The tiered structure of this application appears to be upside-down. The order-line-item objects should exist at a lower level than the user interface layer. The UI can sometimes see the business objects (order, order-line-item, etc.), but the business objects should not know anything about the UI.

If you can invert this structure, it will make the code much cleaner.

Comment: I neglected to mention that before asking here I also did as you suggested and passed the current current form into the struct constructor and tried to use it.  I forget exactly what went wrong with that but I think it was the same object reference required error.  However I did not use the internal keyword.  I've not heard of that before.  For now to get it working I've made everything public and put the ToString method outside the struct and changed the name.

Comment: Cannot access non static member of outer type via nested type, is the error I got when passing in a reference to the form.

Comment: @slomobile - You should replace `ActiveForm` with the variable that you saved the form reference in when you passed it in to the constructor (as shown in my code listing).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the other form is `Form2` you can cast `ActiveForm` to `Form2`:

```
var form2 = ActiveForm as Form2;
if (form2 != null) // form2 == null if ActiveForm is not of type Form2.
{
    form2.sizeComboBox...
}
```

**Edit:**
Two notes.

1. Instead of getting ActiveForm it is better store form2 in a member variable in form1 when form2 is created.
2. You should encapsulate the getting of combobox values behind a property in Form2, like `SelectedFooValue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internal static Form1 ActiveForm { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ActiveForm = this;
    }

    public struct OrderLineItem
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ActiveForm.sizeComboBox.Items[index].ToString();
        }
    }
```

However note that this is not the correct approach. Maybe you can post what you are trying to accomplish and we can help?

Comment: The sizeComboBox.Items collection is filled with different items during the form load event depending on calculations with arguements passed at application launch but the items do not change thereafter.  The OrderLineItem struct contains integer data that needs labels when its ToString is called.  It just so happens that in any case the sizeComboBox contains all the labels I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `ActiveForm` to `Form1`.

Something like this I think (don't have VS open now to check):

```
return someString + ((Form1)ActiveForm).sizeComboBox.Items[index].ToString();
```

However, this is generally not a good way of going about things, you shouldn't make your methods in your classes and structs refer directory to controls since then you tie them together to closely. Try to send the data in to the struct instead or create a method on the form to return the data in some way.